# Prevent Redirects for a python request to a .shtml link

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests, shtml

I am making a python request to a ***.shtml*** link. I want the request to not allow redirects. I am using the following command for this purpose.

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, allow_redirects=False)
```

However, it gets redirected despite the `allow_redirects` option set to `false`. The same *.shtml* URL returns **302** response on the browser, but it returns **200** with the above python request. I want a possible way to stop the request from getting redirected, just like it's happening on the browser.
Moreover, the `response.history` returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The `python requests` deal `.shtml` the same way it deals with `.html`. In my case, the issue was with the URL.